# Beacon found but RSSI is 0, Accuracy -1 and Proximity unknown

Tags: ios, ibeacon, proximity, rssi

I have written a Application detecting IBeacons (swift, IOS).
While i can detect another iPhones RSSI, Accuracy and Proximity correctly, when detecting my beacon (Qualcomm), it gets found, but does not display any useful values for the mentioned Variables. 
Other Apps, downloaded from the App Store, also return the same (useless) values.
I therefore assume that it's not an explicit code bug, but has to do with the beacon (Maybe there are not enough packages being sensed by my Phone).
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typically happens when the power calibration constant is incorrectly set in the beacon.  This constant should be set to the measured RSSI at one meter.  A typical value is -59.  You may wish to see if you can configure this value in the Gimbal admin console.

It is also possible that the battery is low in the beacon and the signal is very weak.  Replacing the battery may resolve the issue.

Comment: A couple of possibilities are listed in the answer.  Can you please comment on what was the issue?